# Write a function that can be invoked as ('say')('hi')()

Tags: javascript

Write a function that can be invoked as a function that returns a function until no arguments are present, then it returns a string.

```
console.log(say('my')('name')('is')('bob')()); => 'my name is bob.'
console.log(say('hello')('world')()); => 'hello world.'
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a function that return an anonymous function. This anonymous function call the original function recursively to build the string and return it when there is no argument provided.

```js
function say (value){     
    return function (str){
      return str === undefined ? (value + ".") : say(value + " " + str);
  } 
}

console.log(say('my')('name')('is')('bob')());
console.log(say('hello')('world')());
```

Comment: yes, it is so simple once you step back and look at it, but when your under the gun, having to do it on a white board, i lost train of thought. At first the last () call with nothing provided was not included in the original question.

Comment: @jonniedollas Without the last empty call `()`, one way to achieve the same solution would be to override your function `.toString()` method to return the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *recursion* to call the same function.

```js
function say(msg) {
  if (msg.indexOf('undefined') == -1) {
    return function(m) {
      return say(msg + ' ' + m);//recursion
    };
  }
  return msg.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');//remove last 'undefined'
}
console.log(say('my')('name')('is')('bob')()); //=> 'my name is bob.'
console.log(say('hello')('world')()); //=> 'hello world.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

```
function say(a) {
    let str = [];
    function _say(s) {
        if (s) {
            str.push(s);
            return _say;
        }
        return `${str.join(' ')}.`;
    }
    return _say(a);
}

console.log(say('my')('name')('is')('bob')());
console.log(say('hello')('world')());
```